# How to make icon size same in landscape mode and potrait mode in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I am a beginner in xamarin.forms. I am using Xamarin.forms Absolute layout for identifying the message count. When in potrait mode, it works fine. In landscape mode, it is giving an enlarged icon. Is there a way we can change this ? Please suggest .

Here is my Xaml file:

```
<effect:BudocodeButton x:Name="chatMsgCnt" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds=".9,0,.4,.9" BorderRadius="12" 
                                           AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional,SizeProportional" BackgroundColor="Red" TextColor="White" FontSize="Medium" Text="{Binding ChatMsgCount}" FontAttributes="Bold" >
```

[landscapeimg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzNj5.png)

[potraitimage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NcBD.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your hight and the width static for the view and set **AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags** to X&Y Proportional.

**Code:**

```
<effect:BudocodeButton 
 x:Name="chatMsgCnt" 
 AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds=".9,0,60,60"
 BorderRadius="12" 
 AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="XProportional,YProportional"
 BackgroundColor="Red" 
 TextColor="White" 
 FontSize="Medium" 
 Text="{Binding ChatMsgCount}" 
 FontAttributes="Bold">
```